# IF para definir impressora padrão via batch

Tags: windows, batch, impressora, windows-10, bat

Estamos reformulando o parque de máquinas aqui da empresa e as máquinas novas vieram com Windows 10, ao contrário do Windows 7 que usávamos antes. O primeiro problema que tivemos foi com a forma que o Windows 10 gerencia a impressão, através do seu gerenciado e não através da impressora padrão.
Consegui desabilitar isso atraves de um arquivo batch que se inicia a cada usuário que loga na máquina, alterando o registro correspondente.

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" /v LegacyDefaultPrinterMode /t "REG_DWORD" /d "1" /f
```

O problema agora é que é desativado o Gerenciador de impressão, mas o Windows coloca qualquer uma das impressoras como padrão. Continuei então o batch para, caso tenha uma impressora conectada via USB, aquela impressora seja usada como padrão

```
wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter
```

Contudo, alguns computadores usam impressoras remotas, mapeadas como portas locais, através do nome do computador "\\NomeDoComputador\SamsungM" (Nome padronizado para o compartilhamento das impressoras).
Eu tentei, então, modificar o arquivo para que ele mesmo faça a seleção da impressora padrão. Caso exista impressora conectada via USB, que use ela, caso contrário, que use a impressora que tem como porta "%SamsungM", mas meu código não está funcionando...

```
set var=wmic printer get portname
%var% > portas.txt
if /I "%samsungm" == "portas.txt" equal (
wmic printer where "PortName like '%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter
) else (
wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter
)
```

Os comandos individuais para setar a impressora como padrão funcionam, então acredito que seja algo no meu If que está errado.

Comment: Acho que essa parte do "equal" no if também não deveria estar ali...

Answer (score 0):

Não se pode comparar pedaço de texto numa cláusula "IF" no DOS, por isso nunca funcionará.

O que você quer fazer é verificar se um determinado padrão de texto existe na saída de um comando. No DOS, o comando mais indicado para esta tarefa é o FINDSTR.

```
wmic printer get portname | findstr /eric:"samsungm *">NUL
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" (
    wmic printer where "PortName like '%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter
) else (
    wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter
)
```